# Try except in finally block, log second exception

Tags: python, exception, try-except

I have this try, except, finally block in which I need to catch an exception and raise if thrown, and then `finally` execute another block of code that could fail, but if it raises an exception then log an error with the new exception message whilst still later throwing the original exception. Is there anyway I can do this? Currently the original exception message is being displayed from `e.stderr` instead of the new error message.

```py
try:
    yield
except ProcessError:
    raise
finally:
    try:
        session.iam(f"service-id-lock '{service_id_name}' -f")
    except ProcessError as e:
        logger.warning(
            f"Unable to lock service id '{service_id_name}' due to the following error {e.stderr}"
        )
```

Let's say yield throws an error such as:

```py
ProcessError("Error retrieving service-id 'test-id'")
```

And then in the second try block located in `finally` it throws another error such as

```py
ProcessError("Error locking service-id 'test-id'")
```

I'd expect the following line to log the following warning

```py
logger.warning(f"Unable to lock service id '{service_id_name}' 
                 due to the following error 'Error locking service-id 'test-id'")
```

But instead it shows the first error message:

```py
logger.warning(f"Unable to lock service id '{service_id_name}' 
                 due to the following error 'Error retrieving service-id 'test-id'")
```

How should I resolve this?

Comment: The original error message is supposed to be displayed, isn't that what you mean by "still later throwing the original exception"?

Comment: @Barmar tried to update to make it easier to understand.

Comment: Thanks. My confusion was due to not scrolling right to see where you were using `e.stderr`.

Comment: What is `ProcessError`? It's not a standard Python exception. And `stderr` is not an standard exception attribute. I suspect this has something to do with the way the `session` object keeps track of errors, not a general issue with exceptions.

Comment: @Barmar it's a custom exception. I'll take a look at session.

Comment: Can you reproduce this with standard errors? I tried with `ZeroDivisionError` in the outer `try` and `IndexError` in the inner `try`, and I got the expected result.

Comment: @Barmar it was a problem with my test code. Thanks for the help!